# How to use different config file in python for each deploy stage?

Tags: python, maven, deployment

How to use different config file in python for each deploy stage?

I need to use different config file below that.

- Alpha: config.alpha.conf
- Beta:  config.beta.conf
- Production:  config.production.conf

As Java, Maven makes it working.
So what is way in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends much on your application and IDE. [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/specials/pycharm/pycharm.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0YjC3PyY2gIVirftCh1rsAXBEAAYASAAEgJJ4_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CIbNhd78mNoCFQEX4Aodog8BoQ) comes with a lot of options to manage your project, including dev/deploy management tools explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deploying-applications.html).

Good luck!